# REST using several resteasy providers in different war files

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, servlets, resteasy

In the deployed EAR file there are a couple of WARs which configure rest providers.

file1.war:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>
        path1.exception.Mapper1
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/path1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

file2.war:

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>
            path2.exception.Mapper2
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Now when the `/rest/path2` url is used, the `path1.exception.Mapper1` is invoked, although only the `path2.exception.Mapper2` should be used. 
How can I archive it?

I tried to use in web.xml of file1.war:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest/path1/* </param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/path1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

with no success (when try to access the /rest/path2 url, path1.exception.Mapper1 catched it and worked). 
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean 'no success' ?More information, error messages, stack traces are always better than mental power.

Comment: Having the same Problem on Wildfly10. Did you Evers fix this?

Comment: @StefanHaberl, I debugged it and found that resteasy creates a map for exceptions. A key in this map - is a name of exception class, but not the full path. So there is a chance, when an exception, for instance Error1 in both wars, the same handler will be used. A workaround: use different names of exception classes. Or, a better approach: extract exception mappers into a common component, that will be reused by both war files.